# Creating missing ios config caused "Application has not been registered error"

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to build a React Native project from another developer and he didn't commit the ios directory. Now I need to run the app on iOS and tried to use `react-native upgrade` to recreate the iOS config. When I run `react-native run-ios` after `npm install`, I'm getting "Application has not been registered error".

What do I have to change or what is the right way to recreate the iOS settings?

I'm running these commands on a MacOS High Sierra with Xcode 10.

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "thefeedback-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "postinstall": "node ./android-release-gradle-fix.js",
    "clean":" @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./preBuilding.ps1",
    "android": "npm run clean && react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
    "bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "native"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "react": "16.4.0  ",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-background-job": "2.1.1",
    "react-native-easy-toast": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-textfield": "0.12.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "3.2.5",
    "react-native-push-notification": "3.0.2",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "3.3.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "render-if": "0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  }
}
```

The index.js:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/app';

import data from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(data.displayName, () => App);
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

And the app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "25.0.0"
  },
  "name": "TheFeedbackApp",
  "displayName": "TheFeedbackApp"
}
```

It seems that's something related to the name having a hyphen.